# total curvature of surface of revolution with closed profile curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha(t)=(g(t), h(t), 0)$ be a closed unit speed curve on $[a,b]$. $h>0$.

Rotating this curve about the $x$ axis gives a surface of revolution.

Therefore $\alpha(a)=\alpha(b)$. $\|\alpha'\|=1$.

Why is it always true that $h'(a)=h'(b)$?

Comment: What's your definition of a "closed, unit speed curve"?

Comment: well, closed means $\alpha(a)=\alpha(b)$. and unit speed means $\|\alpha'(t)\|=1$.

Comment: Yes, but what are the precise conditions assumed at the endpoints? If $\alpha'(a) = \alpha'(b)$ (or something equivalent) is not part of the definition, there's no reason that $h'(a) = h'(b)$.

Comment: But the textbook uses this to derive that the total curvature of a surface of revolution of a closed profile curve is zero.

Comment: Perhaps your book imposes something along the lines of the velocity being continuous at $\alpha(a) = \alpha(b)$?

Answer (score 0):

I think the closed curve considered here is assumed to be smooth (if it wasn't, the surface would not be smooth either, invalidating the computation of total curvature). That is, the curve is a smooth immersion of the *circle* $S^1$, which  for convenience of computations is written as closed interval $[a,b]$ with the endpoints $a$ and $b$ identified. With the endpoints being identified, the tangent vector (derivative) must be the same at  $a$ and $b$.

In terms of coordinates, the condition $\alpha'(a)=\alpha'(b)$ implies $h'(a)=h'(b)$.